# Getting BlazeInfoException in IntelliJ from the Bazel plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, bazel

I just installed the Bazel plugin for IntelliJ, and I keep getting this exception:

```
com.google.idea.blaze.base.command.info.BlazeInfoException: blaze info failed with exit code: -1
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.google.idea.blaze.base.command.info.BlazeInfoException: blaze info failed with exit code: -1
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:502)
  [...]
  at com.google.idea.blaze.base.async.FutureUtil$Builder.lambda$run$0(FutureUtil.java:93)
  [...]
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:548)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:493)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
  at com.google.idea.blaze.base.async.executor.BlazeExecutor$3.call(BlazeExecutor.java:108)
  at com.google.idea.blaze.base.async.executor.BlazeExecutor$3.call(BlazeExecutor.java:105)
  [...]
Caused by: com.google.idea.blaze.base.command.info.BlazeInfoException: blaze info failed with exit code: -1
  at com.google.idea.blaze.base.command.info.BlazeInfoRunnerImpl.runBlazeInfo(BlazeInfoRunnerImpl.java:105)
  at com.google.idea.blaze.base.command.info.BlazeInfoRunnerImpl.lambda$runBlazeInfo$2(BlazeInfoRunnerImpl.java:75)
  ... 6 more
```

Edit: I am using IntelliJ 2017.3 on MacOS El Capitan 10.11.6, Java JRE 1.8.0, and the Bazel version is 0.8.1-homebrew (the plugin version is 2017.11.20.0.4). I get this error when I try to setup a new Java project (an Hello World with only one class and one BUILD file containing a java_binary similar to [this tutorial](https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/master/java-tutorial/src/main/java/com/example/cmdline)), and it appears when I click on the Bazel sync button.

The output in the Bazel console is:

```
Syncing project: Sync (incremental)...
Updating VCS...
Running Bazel info...
Command:  info --tool_tag=ijwb:IDEA:community --curses=no --color=no --experimental_ui=no --progress_in_terminal_title=no --

==== TIMING REPORT ====

Sync: 47ms
BazelInfo: 4ms

Timing summary:

BlazeInvocation: 4ms
Sync failed
Command: git diff --name-status --no-renames abc8913346474d12ad45226503438848011929ae
```

Does anybody have an idea about what is it and/or how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you using, and which Bazel version? What did you try doing in IntelliJ to see this error?

Comment: Hi László, oh yes sorry, I added these details in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer, thanks to [this post](https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/issues/88).

In **IntelliJ > Settings > Other Settings > Bazel Settings**, the field "Bazel binary location" was empty. For my case, I entered **/usr/local/bin/bazel** and now it works!